# Printing two Jpanels in one document

Tags: java, swing

I have two different Panels but i have need to send them in one document in to two pages. first page print at front and the second will print at the back side can anyone please help me i have send one jpanel but how to send second with it. Here is my code

```
private void printCard() {

        PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printjob.setJobName(" CARD ");
        Printable printable = new Printable() {
                public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
                    if (pageNum > 0) {
                        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                        }

                        Dimension imageDimension = jLayeredPane2.getSize();
                        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageDimension.width, imageDimension.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        jLayeredPane2.print(bufferedImage.getGraphics());
                        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
                        g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                        g2.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, (int) pf.getWidth(), (int) pf.getHeight(), null);

                        Dimension backimage=jLayeredPane4.getSize();
                        BufferedImage bufferedImage1 = new BufferedImage(backimage.width, backimage.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        jLayeredPane4.print(bufferedImage1.getGraphics());
                        g2.drawImage(bufferedImage1, 0, 0, (int) pf.getWidth(), (int) pf.getHeight(), null);
                        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;

                }
        };

        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 153, 243);
        paper.setSize(243, 153);
        PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
        format.setPaper(paper);
        format.setOrientation(PageFormat.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
        printjob.setPrintable(printable,format);

        try {
               printjob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                System.out.println("Sorry No Image Found" + ex);
        }
```

Thanks
    }

Comment: Small remark: If you call BufferedImage.getGraphics() you should always call dispose() on the returned Graphics after you are done painting to it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a java.awt.print.Printable, use java.awt.print.Pageable instead. This will let you specify two pages, and then print in duplex to get front and back. PrinterJob has a setPageable() function as well as a setPrintable(). To make it even easier, use a Book and just add two Printables, one for each page.